# php post form to another php

Tags: php

I want to post a search value from index.php to search.php,

index.php

```
<form action="search.php?val=" method="post">
```

and search.php

```
<?php echo $_GET['val']?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $_POST['val']?>
```

I would like to retain 'val' value in the URL, but search.php could not capture the value of 'val' which appear to be "val=".

Answer (score 1):

Create a text field by the name of `val` inside the form on index file eg:

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="val" value="search string" />
  <!-- more form stuff -->
</form>
```

And you can now get it like:

```
<?php echo $_POST['val']?>
```

If however, you want that value in url you should modify the form's method to `get` like:

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="val" value="search string" />
  <!-- more form stuff -->
</form>
```

and then you can get its value on search page like:

```
<?php echo $_GET['val']?>
```

Alternatively, you can specify search string directly in the `action` attribute of the `form` and in this case you don't need the `val` field:

```
<form action="search.php?val=<?php echo $search_string;?>" method="get">
  <!-- more form stuff -->
</form>
```

and then you can get its value on search page like:

```
<?php echo $_GET['val']?>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking to achieve can be described as URL parameter passing or [query string](http://ditio.net/2008/06/12/php-query-string/). The idea is that you can pass values through the URL, denoted by `?variable=value`. Important parts of URL parameter passing is retrieving the value by using `$_GET`.

Therefore, change this line of code,

```
<form action="search.php?val=" method="post">
```

to this line of code,

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
```

You do not need to add the `action` to include, `?val`,  PHP will do that for you as long as you have an input field with the `name` attribute as `val`.

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="val"/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Once submitted you should have the URL which looks like,

```
http://www.example.com/search.php?val=your_text_here
```

Which from inside `search.php` you can access your query string using, `$_GET` superglobal.

```
<?php
echo $_GET['val'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use both. If you have <form action="search.php?val=...">,
then you can access it just as $_GET["val"]. Any other form elements
will however show up in $_POST[] for your example.

Btw, in cases where the parameter might be submitted by different
forms, use $_REQUEST. It captures both GET and POST content.

Comment: Great! $_REQUEST['val']; method solve it, but is it safe to use this?